# How do I filter the eager loaded class?

Tags: laravel, controller, eager-loading

I have a category class and I am calling all the events inside that class with eager loading. However I only want to show the events that have been approved. I am using a show controller in Laravel.

I have been able to filter the category class using wherehas() but I can't figure out how to filter the result of the eager loaded events class.

```
public function show(Category $category)
    {  
        $cat = $category->with('events')->get();

        return $cat;

        return view('category.show', compact('cat'));
    }
```

Like I said, I've been able to filter the category but how do I send through the category with the events that have approved = 1 instead of null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a callback to the with function that filters the query.

```
$cat = $category->with(['events' => function ($q) {
       $q->where('approved', 1);
    }]
)->get();
```

Comment: That worked to an extent except it is now listing all of my categories. I did some more playing with it and got this to work 
```
$category->load(['events' => function ($query) {
           $query->whereNotNull('approved');
        }])->get();
```
Thanks so much for pointing me in the right direction!